# How to get City name or Street address from lat and long for vue web applications?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, geolocation, google-location-services

I have built a Vue web application and i got the user coordinates using 'vue-browser-geolocation' plugin,
with that coordinates how can I get the city name or streetname,

```
this.$getLocation(options)
  .then(coordinates => {
    console.log(coordinates);
  });
```

From above code i have the access to lat and long

Answer (score 1):

[as explained in detail on google APIs documentation:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse)

```js
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```